# A cumulative sum of consecutive workdays that resets to 1 when consecutive days = 0, per ID

Tags: sql, database, window-functions, impala, gaps-and-islands

I have 3 columns:

Employee ID(numerical)

Day of work(a date yyyy-mm-dd when employee had a shift)

is_consecutive_work_day (1 if days of work are consecutive, else 0)

I need a 4th: Consecutive_work_days (a cumulative sum of is_consecutive_work_day, which resets to 1 when is_consecutive_work_day = 0). So this will go to a maximum of 5 for any employee id. Some will have 1,2,3 others 1,2...etc.

What am failing to figure out is how to write the 4th column (consecutive_work_days). Not how to write a consecutive sum per employee id, but specifically how to reset to 1 when is_consecutive_work_day = 0 per employee id.

May I ask for your help regarding this 4th column please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions. `lag()` lets you access the previous `day_of_work` for the same employee, which you can compare to the current `day_of_work`: if there is a one day difference, then you can set `is_consecutive_work_day` to 1.

```
select
    employee_id,
    day_of_work,
    case 
        when day_of_work 
            = lag(day_of_work) over(partition by employee_id order by day_of_work) 
                + interval 1 day
        then 1
        else 0
    end is_consecutive_work_day 
from mytable
```

To compute the cumulative sum, it is a bit more complicated. We can use some gaps-and-island technique to put each record in the group it belongs to: basically, everytime `is_consecutive_work_day` of `0` is met, a new group starts; we can then do a window `sum()` over each group:

```
select 
    employee_id,
    day_of_work,
    is_consecutive_work_day,
    sum(is_consecutive_work_day) 
        over(partition by employee_id, grp order by day_of_work)
        consecutive_work_days 
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(1 - is_consecutive_work_day) over(partition by employee_id order by day_of_work)  grp
    from (
        select
            t.*,
            case 
                when day_of_work 
                    = lag(day_of_work) over(partition by employee_id order by day_of_work) 
                        + interval 1 day
                then 1
                else 0
            end is_consecutive_work_day 
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this seem like a gap-and-islands problem, there is a simpler solution.  Simply calculate the maximum previous value that is `0` and take the date difference.

The only caveat is if there is none.

That would be:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(day_of_work,
                coalesce(max(case when is_consecutive_work_day = 0 then day_of_work end) over (partition by employee_id),
                         date_add(min(day_of_work) partition by employee_id), 1)
                        )
               ) as fourth_column
from t;
```